# Positioning child panels using FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing

I have two panels:

- `main_panel`
- `child_panel`

The `main_panel` layout is set using:

```
main_panel.setLayout(flowlayout)
```

I then added `child_panel` to `main_panel`:

```
main_panel.add(child_panel)
```

The `child_panel` gets added to `main_panel` but its position is at the cross-section of horizontal midpoint and top vertical section of screen. I want `child_panel` to be at the top left corner, something I could have done by using `child_panel.setlocation(a,b)` method, if I have set the layout of `main_panel` as `null`.

I have used `FlowLayout` here because I want components in the `JPanel` to keep
adjusting with the size of `JFrame`.

So can I add `child_panel` to `main_panel` at the exact location I want, even if I set the `Layout` of `main_panel` as not `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using GridPanelLayout for your case - you can set the element to be in grid location (0,0) and set it to fill horizontal and vertical, which will cause it to scale with size.  You can then follow the look and feel guidelines to get the proper margins and the like.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel child = new JPanel();
        child.add(new JLabel("Label"));
        main.add(child);
        f.getContentPane().add(main);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use SpringLayout, it gives you the ability to exactly place the sides of your panel (NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST) with the sides of any other component (in your case the main panel)

[This tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) would clarify what I am saying